# Bot Framework - Display User's intent

Tags: botframework

Trying to figure out how I can take the intent from LUIS and insert it into the response from the bot. I cannot seem to find the variable/path to this value. I've tried:

```
#intentName
turn.recognized.intents.intentName
luisResult.intents[0]
```

The docs are not helping since it just shows java classes, doesn't directly translate to the Composer app afaik.

Comment: What docs do you mean?

Comment: @KyleDelaney the MBF documentation, though it's hard to find Composer docs vs SDK docs.

Comment: Can you please post links to help people help you? Also, what is your question?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the first intent via the following adaptive expression:

```
${foreach(turn.recognized.intents, x, x.key)[0]}
```